# ASP.NET MVC Code-First EF - Possible to use EF without database create permissions?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first

So I'm working on an ASP.NET project for university. We have to upload our code to a server running IIS and SQL Server 2008. I've written my project using MVC Code-First EF. I understand that the Entity Framework system needs permission to create the database to work properly (you can't just give it an empty database and let it fill it with data). This has created a problem for me since I do not have database creation privileges on the shared SQL Server. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 2):

As you don't have permissions, it sounds like you'd need to get a DBA to create your database  on the server you are trying to deploy to - this could be done from either a database creation script or from a database backup of the db on your dev machine. You can then instruct EF code first not to try to create / update the database automatically by adding this line to your global.asax (or indeed anywhere before you first access the database)

```
Database.SetInitializer<YourContextType>(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an existing database, rather than let EF create one for you. I have done this myself, but admittedly only when using EF Migrations. Otherwise, you run into trouble with missing table exceptions and what not.

When using migrations, just point your connection string to your empty database, create an initial migration to populate the database with your schema and then update the database itself.

See this answer: [How do I create a migration for an existing database in EntityFramework 4.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9270887/how-do-i-create-a-migration-for-an-existing-database-in-entityframework-4-3)

.. which include this nice link to getting started with EF Migrations: http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/using-ef-migrations-with-an-existing-database/

All this is available through Nuget, and if you have access to Pluralsight content, I can highly recommend Julie Lerman's video on the topic.

If you don't want to use Migrations, you can still use Code First if you just create the database objects manually using SMMS, but obviously you have the manual work of keeping your model and the database in sync.